# How to change which window a click in *Occur* buffer affects?

Tags: window, window-splitting, occur

My use case: I am looking at one place in the code in one window (call it window A), have a second window with the SAME code open (window B) in the same frame, together with an *Occur* buffer, that I opened from window B.

Whenever I click in the Occur buffer, it switches to window A, even though Occur was called from window B.

Can I change this behavior? Similar problems might occur with other selection bufers, such as *compilation* or xref and grep results.

Comment: I don't think that is supposed to happen. Do you have a way to reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q`?